# Assign object value inside its own constructor

Tags: c#, json, constructor, this

I'm trying to deserialize a Json file, but I want to do it inside my class constructor.

The function used normally is

```
Model m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(File.ReadAllText(filename));
```

And I want my class to have a constructor like this concept:

```
Model(string filename) {
    this = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(File.ReadAllText(filename));
}
```

I'm new to programming, and I also studied c++ instead of c#.

Also, Model contains a Dictionary of dictionaries and so on.

If I forgot something in my question, let me know.

Comment: No can do. Use a static factory method instead - `Model.CreateFromFile(filename)`

Comment: You can only do that from within structs, but even then it is not a good idea. Instead do what has been suggested, create a factory method.

Comment: Yeah, I think I had that "struct approach" in mind. Thank you @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that inside a constructor. However, you can create an instance through a static method in the `Model` class.

Something like:

```
public static Model CreateFromFile(string filename)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(File.ReadAllText(filename));
}
```

You can then call it wherever you need to create the instance through the filename:
`Model myModel = Model.CreateFromFile("myfile.json");`

Comment: by the way, why do I need the keyword static?

Comment: The `static` keyword is what makes the method static, which allows you to use the method without creating an instance of your class first. If it wasn't static, then you would need to first create an instance and then call the method from that (which would create another instance).